# multiple-cursors mark-all-like-this does not mark all like this

Tags: multiple-cursors

I have a large text file (2352 lines) which periodically contains the word `Generation`. I now want to delete all lines containing this word.
But when I select the word, do `mc/mark-all-like-this`, `C-a` and `C-k` not all instances, but only a few that are nearby, are deleted.

My `mc/cmds-to-run-once` is empty.

Is there a setting so that all file wide instances are marked/deleted?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`multiple-cursors` is not part of Emacs, but is a separate package. You should contact the author to report bugs.

However, your task can be accomplished a different way. Just run `M-x flush-lines` and type in a regexp that matches the lines you want to delete. It sounds like simply typing in “Generation” would do the trick.

You can look up the help for this command with `C-h f`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try flush-lines for now. I thought it was fine to ask the question here since there is a tag and there are other questions about just this package. When I have time I will try and contribute to the project, but since the issues are closed, the only way would be via a pull request.

Comment: Of course it is fine to ask, but as with anything else sometimes the answer is to file a bug report.